# Populating spinner from web-service data in android

Tags: android, web-services, spinner

I've to populate spinner with web-Services data (XML parsing). It containing two attributes like "ID" and "Name".
Code is as follows :

```
    try {

            ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();

            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://10.0.2.2/WebService/Service.asmx/GetService");

                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Table");




                    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                        Node node = nodeList.item(i);



                        Element providerID = (Element) node;
                        NodeList providerIDlist = providerID.getElementsByTagName("id");
                        Element providerIDelement = (Element) providerIDlist.item(0);
                        providerIDlist = providerIDelement.getChildNodes();

                         MProviderIDL = providerIDlist.item(0).getNodeValue();
                         //mprovider.put("MproviderID", MProviderIDL.toString());
                        listdata.add(MProviderIDL);


Element providerName = (Element) node;
                        NodeList providerNamelist = providerName.getElementsByTagName("value");
                        Element prividerNameElement = (Element) providerNamelist.item(0);
                        providerNamelist = prividerNameElement.getChildNodes();
                        //AddImg[i].setTag(((Node) AdvImglist.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                        MProviderNameL = providerNamelist.item(0).getNodeValue();
                        //mprovider.put("MproviderName", MProviderNameL.toString());
                        listdata.add(MProviderNameL);





                        }

                    Spinner spinMProvider=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinMProvider);

                    ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listdata);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
                    spinMobileProvider.setAdapter(adapter);


        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

sending values to data base..

```
private void Send(View v,String Url) {

        HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost(Url); 
        List<NameValuePair> regParams=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         DefaultHttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();  



        regParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_fname",edtFname.getText().toString()));


        regParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_lname",edtLname.getText().toString()));


        regParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_email",edtEmail.getText().toString()));


        regParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_password",edtPassword.getText().toString()));


        regParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_address",edtAddress.getText().toString()));


        regParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Provider", Integer.toString(spinMProvider.getSelectedItemPosition())));
```

My Xml data...

```
<Table diffgr:id="Table4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
<id>11</id>
<value>Cellular South</value>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
<id>10</id>
<value>Cricket</value>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table6" msdata:rowOrder="5">
<id>4</id>
<value>Sprint NexTel</value>
</Table>
```

And Output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bQtI.png).....

I've to display name in spinner list and to pass particular id to database. How to get ID to back-end of text ?

Comment: first grab the data from webservice and save it into the database with tow colums like id and values... get values data alone from database as a list and bind with the spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the id and spinner values in a array list as a group of object let say

```
Class spinnerObj {

String id;
String spinnervalue;
}

Arraylist<spinnerObj> sp = new Arraylist<spinnerObj>():
```

now populate your spinner with the values from this arraylist sppinnervalue;

In your onValueChange method of the spinner you will get the position this will be in the same order you have added, what you can do is then call sp.get(position).getID() you will get the id which you have associated with the spinner value.